# Oracle chatbot integration with WhatsApp

Tags: node.js, chatbot, whatsapp, whatsapi, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I am trying to integrate an oracle chat bot with WhatsApp.

From what i understand

1. direct integration is not feasible in Oracle and we have to use webhooks.
2. WhatsApp does not expose its API directly. We have to go through a WhatsApp client (infra[servers, db] for the client hasto be setup separately)

Can someone provide some useful guidelines(steps) on how to proceed with the integration?

Comment: Have you considered the Whatsapp Business APIs? 
https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api